# android/php record not inserting into mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite

I have a problem inserting my records into mysql table. Only the last record is being inserted.

This is the code I'm working on:

Android

```
   String[] arrDocumentNumber, arrTransactionDate, arrItemCode;

    arrDocumentNumber = dbHelper.getAllDocumentNumbersFromOUTTRANS();
    arrTransactionDate = dbHelper.getAllTransactionDatesFromOUTTRANS();
    arrItemCode = dbHelper.getAllItemCodesFromOUTTRANS();

     protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        for(int i = 0; i < arrDocumentNumber.length; i++){

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DOCUMENTNUMBER, arrDocumentNumber[i] ));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_TRANSACTIONDATE, arrTransactionDate[i] ));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ITEMCODE, arrItemCode[i] )); 

        }

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that insert outtrans url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_insertTo_outtrans,
                "POST", params);

        //obj.put(params);

        //Log.d("JSON", obj.toString());

        // check log cat from response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

   }
```

PHP

```
    <?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if ( isset($_POST['documentnumber']) && isset($_POST['transactiondate']) && isset($_POST['itemcode']) ){

    $documentnumber = $_POST['documentnumber'];
    $transactiondate = $_POST['transactiondate'];
    $locationdate = $_POST['locationdate'];
    $itemcode = $_POST['itemcode'];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $reson = $_POST['reason'];
    $posted = $_POST['posted'];
    $dateposted = $_POST['dateposted'];
    $unitprice = $_POST['unitprice'];

    // include db connect class
    include('dbconnect.php');

    $result = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO outtrans(documentnumber, transactiondate, itemcode) VALUES (:documentnumber, :transactiondate, :itemcode)");


        $result->bindParam(':documentnumber', $documentnumber);
        $result->bindParam(':transactiondate', $transactiondate);
        $result->bindParam(':itemcode', $itemcode); 
        $result->execute();



    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "New record successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Only the last records gets inserted into mysql table. I don't know much about PHP so I might be missing something in my PHP code. Your help will be greatly appreciated by me. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post the code for your JSON Parser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are making the `HttpRequest` only with the last parameter. (i.e) After your for loop is finished, `params` will contain only the last record.
So Move the

```
JSONObject json=jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_insertTo_outtrans,"POST",params);
```

into the for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrDocumentNumber.length; i++)
{
 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DOCUMENTNUMBER, arrDocumentNumber[i] ));
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_TRANSACTIONDATE, arrTransactionDate[i] ));
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ITEMCODE, arrItemCode[i] )); 
 JSONObject json=jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_insertTo_outtrans,"POST",params);
}
```

Comment: thank you dude! You saved my day. God bless you. I will accept your answer soonest.