# Not able to insert data in database through php file in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio

I am trying to insert data in mysql through php file which contains 3 queries in which first select query is executed then insert and after that update.
select and update is done on same table whereas trying to insert in another table through php in android application.

Here is my java code
mainactivity.java

```
package com.lab.myospaz.insert;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private EditText editTextName;
    private EditText editTextnumber;
    private EditText editTextstandard;
    private EditText editTextgender;
    private EditText editTextinstitute;
    private EditText editTextloction;
    private EditText editTextactivation;
    private EditText editTextEmail;

    private Button buttonRegister;

    private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://register.mobilekipathshala.com/StudentActivation.php";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextnumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextnumber);
        editTextstandard = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextstandard);
        editTextinstitute = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextinstitute);
        editTextloction = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextloction);
        editTextgender = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextgender);
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextactivation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextactivation);

        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonRegister){
            registerUser();
        }
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        String full_name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String contact_number = editTextnumber.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String email_address = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String location = editTextloction.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String institute = editTextinstitute.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String standard= editTextstandard.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String gender = editTextgender.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String code = editTextactivation.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        register(full_name,contact_number,email_address,location,institute,standard,gender,code);
    }

    private void register(String full_name, String contact_number, String email_address, String location,String institute,String standard,String gender,String code) {
        class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
            ProgressDialog loading;
            RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait",null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
                data.put("full_name",params[0]);
                data.put("contact_number",params[1]);
                data.put("email_address",params[2]);
                data.put("location",params[3]);
                data.put("institute",params[4]);
                data.put("standard",params[5]);
                data.put("gender",params[6]);
                data.put("code",params[7]);

                String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(REGISTER_URL,data);

                return  result;
            }
        }

        RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
        ru.execute(full_name,contact_number,email_address,location,institute,standard,gender,code);
    }
}
```

here is another class RegisterUser.java

```
package com.lab.myospaz.insert;

/**
 * Created by asus1 on 14-Jul-2016.
 */
import org.apache.http.HttpException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

/**
 * Created by Belal on 8/6/2015.
 */
public class RegisterUserClass {

    public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                                  HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                response = br.readLine();
            }
            else {
                response="Error Registering";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

and here is my php file

```
<?php
//Database Connection

$conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'mobileki_factum', '%bq41214xA5&}wp)o','mobileki_amit');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$sql1="select ";
$code=$_POST['code'];


if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `mobileki_amit`.`activations` WHERE code='$code' AND status='not used'";

$result=$conn->query($query);


if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    $fname=$_POST['fname']; 
    $email=$_POST['email_address'];
    $contact=$_POST['contact_number'];
    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    $location=$_POST['location'];
    $stander=$_POST['standard'];
    $institute=$_POST['institute'];
    $code=$_POST['code'];








$sql1="INSERT INTO `students`(`full_name`, `email_address`, `contact_number`, `gender`, `location`, `standard`, `institute`) VALUES('$fname','$email','$contact','$gender','$location','$stander','$institute');";
if($conn->query($sql1)===TRUE){
    echo "new recored is successful AND";


$mysql_query="UPDATE `activations` SET 
                               `status` = 'in use'
                                WHERE `CODE` = '$code'";
    // or die(mysql_error());

if($conn->query($mysql_query)===TRUE){
    echo "recored is updated successful";
}
else
{
 echo "no recored  updated ";
}


}
else{
echo "not able to insert";

}

when trying to run this i am getting a blank output neither it shows any error nor the data is being inserted.Can anyone tell me where iam getting wrong?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android/php record not inserting into mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562241/android-php-record-not-inserting-into-mysql)

Comment: You posted complete PHP file? or only the partial content